# Iterating through ResultsSet efficiently?

Tags: java, performance, prepared-statement, resultset

I'm working with a larger data set, where the ResultSet from my PreparedStatement queries are between 10,000's to 1,000,000's of rows. Thinking that the operations performed in the loop were inefficient, I commented everything to just run an empty loop. Using the code found in typical ResultSet examples, it takes 1.5 to 2 seconds to iterate through an empty loop of 5k to 20k entries.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
while(rs.next()){
// empty loop
}
logger.info("loop time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
```

This is a serious performance bottleneck for the application. Any suggestions for how to optimize further?

This is on Java1.6 64 bit, modern computer hardware.

*Edit: This is historical data analysis, so there are no writes to the database, only reads while this application runs. The application requires filtering large datasets to get many representative samples, and then doing many one-off calculations on each of these samples.*

Comment: Why you are retrieving these many at once? Whats the purpose?

Comment: use ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY and test if increasing fetch size (`Result.setFetchSize(int)`) helps.

Comment: Can you try with setting some decent [fetchSize](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e16548/resltset.htm#JJDBC28622)

Comment: I tried multiple ints for `rs.setFetchSize(int)` and `ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY` and it seems slightly faster, but not significantly faster. Anything else you recommend trying?

Comment: Use *procedures* or *functions* from your DBMS. Or else you can optimise the query to retrieve less results.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but isn't the speed of iterating through ResultSet independent of the query? Retrieving less total results would sacrifice accuracy of the analysis, which is not an option.

Comment: @John Can you try setting the `fetchSize` at a statement level instead of resultSet. By the way, can you post the numbers with different `fetchSize`, that might help.

Comment: @John Also if you are doing a `select * from...` in your preparedStatement` you may want to consider narrowing the select to fetch only the columns you really want like `select col1, col2 from...`, if possible. This will reduce the amount of data that has to be transferred over the network from database to the application.

Comment: I don't think fetchSize makes a big enough difference. I tried 10, 20, 500, and they were all in the 1.3s to 1.5s range. I think this iteration should take sub 0.1 seconds. The database is stored in memory, and the query only returns 2 columns.

Comment: @John There are chances that the delay could be because of JVM garbage collection. what the the heap memory allocated for this app and enable verbosegc option to see how much of time is getting spent in garbage collection out of that total 2 secs.